# Finding appearance in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that is like

```
  ABC  EFG  HIJ

1 a#@! !@#  a

2 a#@! !@#  b

3 a#@! !@#  a

4 a#@! !@#  b

5 a#@! !@#  a

6 a#@! !@#  a    

7 a#@! !@#  a

8 a#@! !@#  a

9 a#@! !@#  a

10 a#@! !@#  a

....

666666 a#@! !@#  a

666667 a#@! !@#  b

666668 a#@! !@#  a
```

I want to know that is like

a : 300000 (value 'a' count)

b : 366668 (value 'b" count)

max Length appearance a : 11

max Length appearance b : 5

how can I get this value using pandas and numpy?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for get size of values in `HIJ`:

```
s = df['HIJ'].value_counts()
print (s)
a    10
b     3
Name: HIJ, dtype: int64
```

For largest consecutives values get helper `Series` by comparing with shifted column and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `HIJ` and `s1` and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html). Output is `MultiIndex`, so  another `groupby` is by first level and aggregate `max`:

```
s1 = (df['HIJ'] != df['HIJ'].shift()).cumsum()
print (s1)
1         1
2         2
3         3
4         4
5         5
6         5
7         5
8         5
9         5
10        5
666666    5
666667    6
666668    7
Name: HIJ, dtype: int32
```

---

```
print (df.groupby(['HIJ', s1]).size().groupby(level=0).max())
HIJ
a    7
b    1
dtype: int64
```

### ---

If need count by multiple columns:

```
s = df.groupby(['ABC','EFG','HIJ']).size().reset_index(name='COUNT')
print (s)
    ABC  EFG HIJ  COUNT
0  a#@!  !@#   a     10
1  a#@!  !@#   b      3
```

---

```
s = df.groupby(['ABC','EFG','HIJ', s1]).size()
      .groupby(level=[0,1,2]).max().reset_index(name='LONGEST')
print (s)
    ABC  EFG HIJ  LONGEST
0  a#@!  !@#   a        7
1  a#@!  !@#   b        1
```